# Excepción System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException en Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, webservice, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Me encuentro desarrollando una app con Xamarin Forms. En estos momentos trato de enlazar mi aplicación con un Web Service ASMX, pero al ejecutarlo me pinta la excepción:

> system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.

De momento, para verificar la conexión con el mismo, estoy retornando el método `HelloWorld` y adjuntándolo a un sólo ítem de una lista de objetos llamada `lHabitaciones`, la cual la cargo a un ListView. Lo estoy probando directamente de un dispositivo Android.

Mi código es el siguiente:

**XAML Page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:UserControl="clr-namespace:iKinky.Controles;assembly=iKinky"
         x:Class="iKinky.Controles.HabitacionesResultado"
      >
<ListView x:Name="ListaHabitaciones" RowHeight="420"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Constant=50}" >

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <ViewCell.View>
        <Grid Padding="5"  >
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Image Source="{Binding imagen}" Grid.Row="0"></Image>
          <Label Text="{Binding nombre}" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="Red"></Label>
          <Label Text="{Binding hotel}" Grid.Row="2" TextColor="Black"></Label>
          <Label Text="{Binding direccion}" Grid.Row="3" TextColor="Gray"></Label>

          <Grid Grid.Row="4">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="Precio.png" HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
            <Label Text="{Binding precio}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Gray"></Label>
            <Image Source="Tiempo.png" HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Column="2"></Image>
            <Label Text="{Binding tiempo}" HorizontalOptions="Start"  Grid.Column="3" TextColor="Gray"></Label>
          </Grid>

          <Grid Grid.Row="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="500"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="Ubicacion.png" HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
            <Label Text="{Binding distancia}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Gray"></Label>
          </Grid>

          <Image Source="Llamada.png" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalOptions="Start"></Image>
          <Image Source="PedirUber.png" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalOptions="Start"></Image>
          <Image Source="AceptaReservacion.png" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalOptions="Start"></Image>
          <Image Source="Promocion.png" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalOptions="Start"></Image>

        </Grid>
      </ViewCell.View>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

**Código C#**

```
namespace iKinky.Controles
{
public partial class HabitacionesResultado : StackLayout
{
    public event EventHandler HabitacionSeleccion_Click;
    public event EventHandler TagsSeleccion_Click;
    List<entHabitacionResumen> lHabitResumen = new List<entHabitacionResumen>();

    public HabitacionesResultado()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LLenaDatos(1);
        ListaHabitaciones.ItemSelected += HabitacionesResultado_ItemSelected;
        // btnTags.Clicked += BtnTags_Clicked;
    }

    private void BtnTags_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TagsSeleccion_Click != null) { TagsSeleccion_Click(this, e); }
    }

    private void HabitacionesResultado_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (HabitacionSeleccion_Click != null) { HabitacionSeleccion_Click(this, e); }
    }

    private void LLenaDatos(int Carga)
    {
        wsIkinkySoapClient obj = new wsIkinkySoapClient();

        obj.HelloWorldCompleted += Obj_HelloWorldCompleted;
        obj.HelloWorldAsync();
    }

    void Obj_HelloWorldCompleted(object sender, HelloWorldCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            if (e.Result != "")
            {

            }

            lHabitResumen.Add(new entHabitacionResumen("Habitacion.png"
                                                        , "HABITACIÓN ALBERCA LOUNGE"
                                                        , e.Result
                                                        , "Zona Centro, Colonia del Valle"
                                                        , 1500, "5 hrs."
                                                        , "A 25 mins. de distancia."
                                                        , true, true
                                                        ));

            ListaHabitaciones.ItemsSource = lHabitResumen;
        });
    }
}
}
```

**Excepción**

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.

Espero me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema.

Comment: Como dice el error: *Check InnerException for exception details.*, la excepción que recibes contiene muchos más detalles esenciales para averiguar el problema. Por favor incluye los detalles completos de la excepción.

Comment: En Forms me suele ocurrir que me da ese error con algo del xaml que no le gusta, prueba a poner un try catch alrededor del initializeComponent(); y mira la excepcion, que suele venir mejor explicada.

Answer (score 0):

Este error quiere decir que **XAML** tiene algún error:

- Llamas a una función que no exciste en el c#.
- Has llamado a más de un objeto del XAML con el mismo nombre.
- Son errores que la máquina no se va a dar cuenta, pero en ejecutarlo darán este error en ejecutar la view.

Comment: Añade un ejemplo con el código de ejemplo que ayude a resolver la pregunta